# Getting a KeyError when creating a loop to fill a dataframe

Tags: python, database

So I'm working with the Darksky API to store historical weather data into a dataframe. However, I get a KeyError when trying to load the dataframe with data.

How I'm doing this is using a *for* loop that runs over each hour and collects all the hourly data. So when you query the API you get an output like this:

**Output Data**

*weather['hourly']*

{'summary': 'Mostly cloudy starting in the morning.', 'icon': 'partly-cloudy-day', data': [{

- 'time': 1528354800,
- 'summary': 'Partly cloudy',
- 'icon': 'partly-cloudy-night',
- 'precipIntensity': 0,
- 'precipProbability': 0,
- 'temperature': 12.94,
- 'apparentTemperature': 12.94,
- 'dewPoint': 9.36,
- 'humidity': 0.79,
- 'pressure': 1011.4,
- 'windSpeed': 2.2,
- 'windGust': 2.69,
- 'windBearing': 252,
- 'cloudCover': 0.33,
- 'uvIndex': 0,
- 'visibility': 13.81}]}

This data will show for each hour for a given day, or range of days if you loop it. So first I created my dataframe like so:

**Dataframe Creation**

daily_weather = pd.DataFrame(

- {'time': [],
- 'realtime': [],
- 'summary': [],
- 'icon': [],
- 'precipIntensity': [],
- 'precipProbability': [],
- 'temperature': [],
- 'apparentTemperature': [],
- 'dewPoint': [],
- 'humidity': [],
- 'pressure': [],
- 'windSpeed': [],
- 'windGust': [],
- 'windBearing': [],
- 'cloudCover': [],
- 'uvIndex': [],
- 'visibility': []})

Then I'm using a loop to call the API and load the data over  a range of time to fill the dataframe:

**Filling The DataFrame:**

for day in range (1,30):

```
dt = datetime(2018, 6, day).isoformat()

weather = forecast('d783b2b300466c9bd421eb89ebbd2eca', *VICTORIA, time = dt)

weather.refresh(units='si')

for hour in weather['hourly']['data']:

    daily_weather = daily_weather.append(

    {'time': hour['time'],
     'realtime': datetime.fromtimestamp(hour['time']),
     'summary': hour['summary'],
     'icon': hour['icon'],
     'precipIntensity': hour['precipIntensity'],
     'precipProbability': hour['precipProbability'],
     'temperature': hour['temperature'],
     'apparentTemperature': hour['apparentTemperature'],
     'dewPoint': hour['dewPoint'],
     'humidity': hour['humidity'],
     'pressure': hour['pressure'],
     'windSpeed': hour['windSpeed'],
     'windGust': hour['windGust'],
     'windBearing': hour['windBearing'],
     'cloudCover': hour['cloudCover'],
     'uvIndex': hour['uvIndex'],
     'visibility': hour['visibility'],
     }, ignore_index=True)
```

If I only include the first few parameters the code works, but I get an error when using everything:

[**KeyError**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNqSZ.jpg)

I'd love any direction please. I am stumped.

Comment: You may get some better answers over on our developer-focused sister site. We'll see about getting the question migrated over there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [their documentation](https://darksky.net/dev/docs#data-point-object), it says that `precipIntensity`, like many other values, is optional. To prevent errors like this from happening, use `hour.get('precipIntensity, 0)` to default to 0 - though you can also default to `None` if you want